# Determine which of 3 values is highest and add its value

Tags: vb.net

My code needs to take the highest value of 3 lines and add it to the "line" property.  However it's not behaving how I would expect, I'm having erroneous errors in all 3 lines where I assume it adds the wrong values, resulting in line merging and text overlapping.

`item_title_lines` value should be added if higher than remark lines and it's over 1.

`item_remark_lines` value should be added if higher than remark lines and it's over 1, or if both values are the same.

`unit_lines` has a max value of 2.  This is only added if both values are 1.

```
If item_title_lines > item_remark_lines And item_title_lines > 1 Then line = line + item_title_lines
If item_remark_lines > item_title_lines And item_remark_lines > 1 Then line = line + item_remark_lines
If item_remark_lines = item_title_lines Then line = line + item_remark_lines
        End If
        End If
If item_remark_lines = 1 And item_title_lines = 1 Then
        line = line + unit_lines
        End If
```

Another variation of this I've tried is

```
If Math.Max(item_title_lines, item_remark_lines) >= unit_lines Then 
                line = line + Math.Max(item_title_lines, item_remark_lines) 'Add highest of those values to line count
                Else 
                line = line + unit_lines 'Otherwise, add unit lines to line count
                End If
```

Which achieves the same results.  Is there a more elegant way of comparing 3 values and adding the highest?

Comment: Just put all the values into an array and call `Max` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this one:

```
line += {item_title_lines, item_remark_lines, unit_lines}.Max()
```

Comment: this is C#, not vb.net

Comment: this works without problems in vb.net, at least for me in vs2017

Comment: I stand corrected. It's clearly been too long since I've done some VB I suppose :-)